# команда TEST assembler

Tags: ассемблер

По какому принципу работает команда *TEST*?

Понятно, что это *логическое и*. Устанавливаются флаги. Сколько их и по какому принципу они устанавливаются, если в результате применения к двум числам логической функции получается число?

```
    mov ax,5878h
    mov bx,6B36h
    mov cx,5CFDh
P:  mov  al,bl
Q:  test bh,cl
    jpe  E
    mul ch
    shl  ax,3
    jmp F
E:  imul cl
    xor  cl,ah
F:  sub  ah,cl
```

Вот еще пример, в нем при применение теста - результат *True*, как это получилось?

Comment: А вы пробовали _assembler test_ в Google набирать?

Comment: пробовал, вот и пишу что вычитал

Comment: ассемблер знаю на уровне mov ax,bx, для поступления нужно...

Comment: Какой именно ассемблер? x86?

Comment: Какой именно ассемблер? x86?   да

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: А какая разница 16, 32 или 64 битный режим? Из названия регистров же видно что это Intel-архитектура и этого факта более чем достаточно для того чтобы сообразить что надо залезь в Intel Volume 2

Comment: @sys_dev Кроме архитектур x86/x64 есть много других. ARM, PowerPC или, скажем, К1801ВМ1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TEST` устанавливает флаги PF, SF и ZF.

- Parity Flag - 1, если в результате AND четное количество установленных (1) бит.
- Sign Flag - 1, если результат AND получился отрицательным (старший - знаковый - бит = 1)
- Zero Flag - 1, если результат AND = 0

и сбрасывает CF и OF. Вот общая схема:

```
Operation
TEMP ← SRC1 AND SRC2;
SF ← MSB(TEMP);
IF TEMP = 0
    THEN ZF ← 1;
    ELSE ZF ← 0;
FI:
PF ← BitwiseXNOR(TEMP[0:7]);
CF ← 0;
OF ← 0;
```

Сам результат AND при этом выбрасывается. В вашем примере:

```
6Bh AND FDh = 69h = 01101001b
```

PF будет установлен в 1. `jpe` прыгнет.